# How to link the movement of a div to the movement of another div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an alcohol simulator, so when I press a button, you see an alcohol bottle being drained, but at the same time I should see the stomach filling. I have a code already for 'drinking', but I want to fix that if the water of the bottle moves 2 steps, that the water of the stomach only moves one step. I'll put just the js here, if you want the html as well, let me know.

Edit! Here's my whole code:

```
<!Doctype>

<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="alcoholcss.css" >

<title>Demo of changing position of an Image in JavaScript</title>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>


var top_max = 475,
    top_min = 400,
    left_max = 200;

function move_img(str) {
    var step = 1; // change this to different step value
    var el = document.getElementById('i1');
    var el2 = document.getElementById('i2');

    if (str == 'up' || str == 'down') {
        var top = el.offsetTop;
        var height = el.offsetHeight;
        console.log(height);
        if (str == 'up') {
            top -= step;
            height += step;
        } else {
            top += step;
            height -=step;
        }
        if (top_max >= top && top >= 110) {
            document.getElementById('i1').style.top = top + "px";
            document.getElementById('i1').style.height = height;
        } else {
            clearInterval(myVar)
        }
    } else if (str == 'left' || str == 'right') {
        var left = el.offsetLeft;
        if (str == 'left') {
            left += step;
        } else {
            left -= step;
        }
        if (top_left < left && left >= 0) {
            document.getElementById('i1').style.left = top + "px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(myVar)
        }
    }



}


function auto(str) {
    myVar = setInterval(function () {
        move_img(str);
    }, 90);
}

function nana() {}

var myVar;

function handler() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    auto(this.id);
}



function auto(str) {

 myVar = setInterval(function(){ move_img(str); }, 50)  ;



}


function stop(){

setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( myVar ); }, 1);


}

</script>

</head>

<body>







<img src="http://i.imgur.com/axFc9XD.jpg" id='wodkafles' >

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4mj7HBr.png" id='maag' > 

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SBALEsj.png" id='i2' >
<div id="i1" >

<svg >

    <filter id="multiply">

        <feBlend mode="multiply"/>

    </filter>

    <image id="kitten" width="60%" height="60%" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/8ua9t3W.png" />



</svg>

</div>

<!--<div style="width: 800px; height: 40px"> -->



  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/g2qtHUP.png" id='wodkavoor' "> 

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/WugtAdJ.png" id='maagvoor' > 


 <!-- <img src="http://narutobase.net/forums/customavatars/avatar214268_67.gif" id='i2' style="position:absolute; left: 178; top: 65; height: 59%;"> -->




<br><br><br><br>

<input type=button onClick="auto('up')" class="up" style="position: absolute;" value='Up'>

<br>

<input type=button onClick=move_img('left') class="left"  style="position: absolute; top: 300px; " value='Left'>

<input type=button onClick="stop()" class="right" style="position: absolute;" value='stop'>

<br>

<input type=button onClick=auto('down') class="down" style="position: absolute;" value='down'>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.divtest{
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
height: 20px;
padding-top: 0px;

}

#myDiv{
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 10px;
background-color: transparant;
}

#myDiv img
{
max-width:60%; 
max-height:60%;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}



#wodkafles {

    top: 10px;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 80; 
    height: 70%;"
}

#maag {

    top: 150px;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 246; 
    height: 57%;"
}

#maagvoor{
    top: 150px;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 246; 
    height: 57%;"
}
#i2{
top: 330px;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 316; 
    height: 37%;"
}
#wodkavoor{

    top: 10px;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 80; 
    height: 70%;"
}

#i1 {
     -webkit-o-mox-filter:url(#multiply);
    top: 475px;
    position:absolute; 
left: 85;
    height: 100%;"
    width: 50px;
}
```

i won't make a jsfiddle, those things never work for me and i'd change some stuff because it's 'pixel-related' and i'd need to upload the images etc. etc. etc.

Comment: JS only not enough, if you provide code in jsfiddle, would be better.

Comment: what if I gave you the whole code? I told you, jsfiddle wont work

Comment: Go on and edit [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5j6jv6u/), I see only up, down, stop working at bottom image.

Comment: My favourite bit is `function nana() {}`

Comment: Heh, programing should be fun :) On Google home page you may see `onload="window.lol&&lol()"`

Comment: hey, i know i already tried, but it's too much effort, and I dont want to waste my time with that. you could copy and paste it on notepad and run it :)